# Replication from one Gerrit to another

Tags: replication, gerrit

I want to replicate one project/repository from one Gerrit to another Gerrit. My replication config:

```
[remote "gerrit3"]
  url = 192.168.1.106:29418/${name}
  adminUrl = gerrit+ssh://192.168.1.106/
  push = refs/*:refs/*
  replicatePermissions = true
  replicateHiddenProjects = true
  mirror = false
  projects = tests/test1
  replicationDelay = 0
  createMissingRepositories = true
```

After triggering replication I see following messages in replication log:

```
[2019-07-25 14:11:00,249] [] scheduling replication tests/test1:..all.. => 192.168.1.106:29418/tests/test1
[2019-07-25 14:11:00,251] [] scheduled tests/test1:..all.. => [f208c682] push 192.168.1.106:29418/tests/test1 to run after 0s
[2019-07-25 14:11:00,253] [f208c682] Replication to 192.168.1.106:29418/tests/test1 started...
[2019-07-25 14:11:00,463] [f208c682] Missing repository created; retry replication to 192.168.1.106:29418/tests/test1
[2019-07-25 14:12:00,465] [f208c682] Replication to 192.168.1.106:29418/tests/test1 started...
[2019-07-25 14:12:00,689] [f208c682] Missing repository created; retry replication to 192.168.1.106:29418/tests/test1
[2019-07-25 14:13:00,690] [f208c682] Replication to 192.168.1.106:29418/tests/test1 started...
[2019-07-25 14:13:00,996] [f208c682] Missing repository created; retry replication to 192.168.1.106:29418/tests/test1
```

Last two lines keep repeating forever. It looks like source Gerrit doesn't see remote repository, no matter if remote repo exists or not. If not it creates empty repo properly but after this Gerrit still doesn't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in `url` line. Documentation examples show url without protocol specified but also mention that `url` parameter is compatible with `git push` url syntax. After change `url` line to:

```
url = ssh://gerrit@192.168.1.106:29418/${name}
```

problem is gone. Gerrit starts to see remote repo.